Vulkan Queue Sync with multiple renderpasses
On the command buffers for the graphics queue I am submitting multiple renderpasses/subpasses (shadow map/defered/resolve) and I now want to add a compute shader that generates some mesh data that should be used by the vertex shader in the defered renderpass.
My current plan is to have separate command buffers and signal a semaphore when submitting the command queue. I then wait on the semaphore in te graphics queue.
From a data point of view, the compute shader in the compute queue and the shadow map shader in the graphics queue could run in parralell. In my head the dependecies look somewhat like this:
comput  shadow_map
  |        |
  |        |
  v        |
defered    |
   \      /
   |     |
   v     v
   resolve


I am roughly following this resource vulkan-tutorial.com/Compute_Shader but they only have one renderpass and wait for its VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_VERTEX_INPUT_BIT. With my setup I would assume this causes the shadow_map vertex stage to wait for the compute shader.
Is there a way to get inbetween the renderpasses of the graphics queue?

Hard to give concrete answer with no code. What are your submissions, what stage flags you have on the sems, etc?

You don't need two queues if all you are trying to do is make sure it's possible for two render passes to not have execution dependencies on one another.  Nearly everything is async in vulkan by default, you would need explicit synchronization to gauantee two draw calls out side of subpasses would happen one after another.


Is there a way to get in between the render passes of the graphics queue?

If you are submitting both render passes in a single queue submit, no.
Vulkan command buffers are defined as sequences of work, albeit sequences than can be pipelined across multiple pipeline stages. The only tool you have for synchronization across queues is synchronization with the submit-time semaphores, and so the only point you can inject those syncs is at the start of the sequence in the command buffer. There is no way to defer a cross-queue sync to apply midway through a command buffer.
There are split-scope synchronization primitives, VkEvents, but they are explicitly not allowed for cross-queue synchronization because there is a risk of deadlocks.
Do you actually need to submit the compute work to a different queue? If you submit within the same queue then you can either use events or just use a normal srcStage=COMPUTE pipeline barrier before the first render pass.
